# Integral of a linear function with constant value of $x$ ($x=3$)

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am doing fuzzy logic and I need to use a method that calculates:

$$ \frac{\int x\mu(x)dx}{\int \mu(x)dx}$$

Now, what I need to do is find the four linear equations that make up  the function. We can see that it is formed by four linear equations, and I have found that (left to right) $y_1 = 0.5x-1$, $y_2 = ?$, $y_3 = 1$, $y_4 = -\frac{x}{3} + \frac{8}{3}$. Of course, we'd integrate $y_1$ in the bounds $2$ to $3$ and so on.

[image]

My question now is: What do I do with $y_2$? I know that I can represent it by $x=3$, but I can't express it in terms of $y_3=...$ so I can calculate an integral.

Comment: What you’ve drawn for $\mu(x)$ isn’t a function.  Perhaps $\mu(x)$ has a jump discontinuity at $3$?

Comment: @MichaelBurr I haven't drawn anything, this is what I've been given without any mentions of it being non-continuous in a point. However, now that I think about it, it does make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The vertical segment of the curve is indeed described by $x = 3$ and $0.5\le y\le 1$. Since there is no change along the $x$ direction, this portion of the curve contributes zero to the overall integral (recall that an integral represents the area under the curve.)

The reason we cannot find an expression for $y$ in terms of $x$ for this vertical segment is that, in this portion of the curve, there are many (i.e., more than one) values of $y$ associated with a given value of $x$, namely $x = 3$. In mathematical terminology, the said portion of the curve is *not a function.*

Comment: Thanks, very insightful!